# How to use `join` with an array

Tags: github-actions

I want to join an array of strings into one string inside an expression.

So I tried using the `join` function for that like this:

```yaml
env:
  WINDOWS_DATABASE_PATH: ${{join(['file:', env.RUNNER_TEMP, '\windows_database.db'], '')}}
```

I expect to get this as the variable:

```
file:some\path\here\windows_database.db
```

But instead I get the following error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/release.yml (Line: 12, Col: 26):
Unexpected symbol: '['. Located at position 6 within expression: join(['file:', env.RUNNER_TEMP, '\windows_database.db'], '')
```

How do I properly use this function with an array?
The docs state that the function does accept arrays but does not provide usage examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#join) and this community [issue](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/11401), it looks like the syntax is not available to be used with the `join()` expression.

Though, you may workaround it by adding an intermediate job as suggested in this [comment](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/11401#discussioncomment-2262202).

---

As for the solution, the one that you figured out is close. You may modify that like this:

```yaml
env:
  WINDOWS_DATABASE_PATH: file:${{ env.RUNNER_TEMP }}\windows_database.db
```

Another alternative could be to use [`format()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#format) expression like this:

```yaml
env:
  WINDOWS_DATABASE_PATH: ${{ format('file:{0}\{1}', env.RUNNER_TEMP, 'windows_database.db') }}
```

or,

```yaml
env:
  WINDOWS_DATABASE_PATH: ${{ format('file:{0}\windows_database.db', env.RUNNER_TEMP) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working like this.
This however does not use the `join` function, so if anyone knows how to use it here, please post an answer.

```
env:
   WINDOWS_DATABASE_PATH: 'file:${{github.workspace}}\windows_database.db'
```

For my example please note that I am not using `env.RUNNER_TEMP` anymore but `github.workspace` which is a github context and not a default github environment variable, which did not work for me.